# Postgresql - "IN empty array" syntax

Tags: postgresql

I create programmatically sql queries to Postgresql like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1, 2, 3);
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1);
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ();
```

The last query generates a syntax error. How should I handle this special case and write an empty array here?

Answer (score 3):

Internally,

```
col IN (1, 2, 3)
```

is converted to

```
col = ANY (ARRAY[1,2,3]::integer[])
```

That syntax will also work for empty arrays:

```
col = ANY (ARRAY[]::integer[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery that returns no results:

```
select null where 0 = 1
```

The `null` here should be implicitly cast-able to any type as well. It's only significant that the query returns no results. For you case it would work just as well to use `select 0` or some other integer if that seems clearer to you.

While you could insert a literal `null` value into the list I wouldn't recommend that. There are some platforms that have server settings which do allow for null equality tests. And I suspect the optimizer will handle the subquery form better. While this wouldn't work on Oracle without adding `from dual` this it also generally portable.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, we try to handle this case (empty array) explicitly in the code and then we avoid the database call.

However, when we need a quick workaround we add a readable string condition that is always `false`:

```
'COLNAME array' = 'is empty'
```

where `COLNAME` is replaced with the real column-name

Details:

- the array cast `col = ANY (ARRAY[]::integer[])` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63905461/1041641) requires us to know the column type
- the numeric check `0 = 1` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63905381/1041641) works, but makes debugging tricky, because we don't know which column had the empty array

  - workaround could be to add a comment after the condition: i.e. `0=1 --COLUMN array is empty`

    - but this can cause issues when multiple conditions are concatenated
      i.e. you may get `0=1 --COLUMN array is empty AND OTHER_COL > 2`

      - workaround for this could be to append a line-break after the comment: `0=1 --COLUMN array is empty\n`, but this is brittle and changes the desired format
- we cannot simply use `'COLNAME' = 'array is empty'`, because this may return true, when the column really contains the string `array is empty`